# Blender modal operator cannot insert keyframe and move object

Tags: python, modal-dialog, operator-keyword, blender

In Blender I am using the modal operator template to move an object and record its position as a keyframe.

I am doing something like this:

```
import bpy
from bpy.props import IntProperty, FloatProperty

class ModalOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Move an object with the mouse, example"""
    bl_idname = "object.modal_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Modal Operator"

    first_mouse_x = IntProperty()
    first_value = FloatProperty()
    current_frame = 1
    endframe = bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].frame_end

    def modal(self, context, event):
        if event.type == 'MOUSEMOVE':
            if self.current_frame < self.endframe:
                delta = self.first_mouse_x - event.mouse_x
                context.object.location.x = self.first_value + delta * 0.01
                context.scene.frame_set(self.current_frame)
                bpy.ops.anim.keyframe_insert_menu(type="Rotation")
                bpy.ops.anim.keyframe_insert_menu(type="Location")
                self.current_frame+=1

        elif event.type == 'LEFTMOUSE':
            return {'FINISHED'}

        elif event.type in {'RIGHTMOUSE', 'ESC'}:
            context.object.location.x = self.first_value
            return {'CANCELLED'}

        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}
```

Happens that before it inserts all keyframes and only after you can move the cube with the mouse, for instance. I would like to move the cube and "record" its movement at the same time. Is there a solution for that?

Answer (score 1):

The easy solution would be to enable blenders [Auto Keyframing](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/timeline.html#keyframe-control).

If you still want to get your operator working, I expect you will need to not call other operators and work with the data directly, particularly within a modal operator.

```
context.object.keyframe_insert('location')
context.object.keyframe_insert('rotation_euler')
```

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your answer.
Right now I am using blender 2.79. If I enable auto keyframing, or also with the solution you offered, I have the exact same problem.

In fact, auto-keyframing works if, for instance, I grap the object with G. It doesn't if I move it by script, don't know why.

Comment: @PaoloGambardella I don't think you can have two modal operators running at the same time and both reacting to user input. With auto keyframing you can start playback and edit your data while frames are rolling, no script required at all.

Comment: I understand what you are saying but if I play (ALT+A) with autokeyframing on and after I activate the script, it doesn't work. And it doesn't also if I first run the script and then play.

Comment: @PaoloGambardella that's two separate solutions that you're mixing together. Please don't. Auto keyframing presumably does what you initially intended, there is no need for extra operator here. If that's not the case - I see two solutions, either emulating other operators inside yours (i.e. reacting to standard hotkeys, performing similar actions, etc.) or setting redraw callback and attempting to intercept things here; both will require quite large code and presumably will interfere with 'usual' workflow.

Comment: @keltar thank you for your answers.
I am not mixing the two approaches, in fact I tried also to remove the calls to keyframe_insert, etc and still I cannot record anything.

Now I am simply moving my object and nothing happens, even with autokeyframe insertion activated. Instead if I move my object with the Grab functionality, it works.

It's like the modal operator created by me blocking the other functionality.

Comment: @PaoloGambardella yes it does exactly that. You consume user input events in your `modal` function. You can pass on some events if you're not interested in them but want other operators to react with `return {"PASS_THROUGH"}`, but if you pass e.g. `g` key - grab operator will start its modal operation and you'll no longer get any events until it completes.

Comment: that is strange, isn't it? I mean:
- I start with ALT+A. After I press G and it starts record. Everything OK
- I start with ALT+A. After I run a script which moves the object and NOTHING is recorded. Why?

Comment: @PaoloGambardella Alt-A and G,S,R will record you manually moving an object. If you are using a script to move it, have the script also make keyframes while it is moving, like [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/75160/935).

Comment: this doesn't work either. In case I do something like this, in fact, it simply  record all the keyframes and only then it moves the object with my controller.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved this one.

I was calling the keyframe_insert for the wrong object (anim, instead of the cube itself)

This is the proper way to insert it, for example when the object is a camera:

```
camera = bpy.context.scene.camera
camera.keyframe_insert(data_path='location', index=0)
camera.keyframe_insert(data_path='location', index=1)
camera.keyframe_insert(data_path='location', index=2)
camera.keyframe_insert('rotation_quaternion')
```

in this way the keyframes are inserted on play.